# ReactJS: Unable to set "Active" class on ReactProSidebar Menu Item

Tags: reactjs

I am using React Pro Sidebar navigation (https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar) and I am not too sure how to set the `active` prop on a selected menu item from a menu that has multiple links.

code:

```js
<SidebarContent>
  <Menu iconShape="square">
    <MenuItem icon={<IoHomeOutline />}>
      Home
      <Link to="/home" />
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem icon={<IoPeopleOutline />}>
      HighSev OnCalls
      <Link to="/oncalls" />
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem icon={<IoCellularOutline />}>
      Reports
      <Link to="/reports" />
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</SidebarContent>;
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced direct usage of `window.location` with the `useLocation()` hook from `react-router-dom`. It's straightforward to integrate into a React router app. One issue I encountered was related to nested routes where the exact match check didn't cover all scenarios. For example, if the current route is `/home/details`, the sidebar wouldn't reflect the active state for `/home/`. To resolve this, I assigned unique keys to each sidebar item and checked whether they were present in the URL. This approach allowed me to ensure sidebar items reflected their active state accurately regardless of nested routes.

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const location = useLocation();

{item.menuItems.map((menuItem) => (
  <MenuItem
    active={location.pathname.includes(menuItem.key)}
    className={classes.sidebarMenuItem}
    key={menuItem.key}
    icon={menuItem.icon}
    component={<Link to={menuItem.url} />}
  >
    {menuItem.name}
  </MenuItem>
))}
```

Answer (score 4):

On the [documentation](https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar#api) itself has defined prop `active` on `MenuItem`

#UPDATED

Check if your current path is same as link's path then set that `MenuItem` to `active`. Same for other items too.

```
<MenuItem active={window.location.pathname === "/home/"} icon={<IoHomeOutline />}>
  Home
  <Link to="/home" />
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thats correct, however how would you set Active on multiple links depending on which one was selected?

Comment: Can you share some code demo? I am not able to understand your requirement. Active can be set on `MenuItem` not on links, `menuitem` can have multiple links.

Comment: The ```Active``` class should be set to true on a MenuItem that is active by the user (user clicks on the link or is determined by route). I am unsure how this ```Active={true}``` would work on multiple ```MenuItems```

Comment: So you're asking how will you determine which menuitem to set active to true?

Comment: Check my updated answer. hope that's what you want !

Comment: @ayushlal So did you get the active prop to work? I've used the same method provided here but no active class or anything was added to the clicked ```MenuItem```. I also received the ```Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `active`.``` error when using this method.

Comment: @Lance I've been using the solution above and setting the active prop/class based on url path seems to be a pretty good solution to this

Comment: @ayushlal if the menu has the active prop, there will be a class like "is active" added to the menu item? Mine just won't react to anything even if I've used the same solution above. I had to do something like this: ```className={`${location.pathname === '/' ? 'sidebar-menu active' : ''}`}``` to replicate the same function.